# Wordpress wpdb->update multiple "WHERE" ID's

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, php-7

PHP rookie here:

I need to use `$wpdb->update` to update all my database rows that have the value "NULL" with the current date time.

This is the MySQL that works when I plug directly into PHPMyAdmin

```
UPDATE `mytable`
SET `expired` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE (`id` > 1 AND `expired` IS NULL)
```

Using `$wpdb` I've figured out that I need to get all the ID's that need expired like so:

```
$get_ids = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT id
    FROM $database
    WHERE (`id` > 1 AND `expired` IS NULL)
");
```

So now I have an array of ID's and my thought was to just put them in the `$wpdb->update` like so

```
foreach($get_ids as $key => $value){
    $data = array('expired' => $currentTime);
    $where = array('id' => $value);

    $wpdb->update(
        $database,
        $data,
        $where,
    );

    print_r( $where );
}
```

The print_r returns

```
 "Array
(
    [id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 34
        )

)
Array
(
    [id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 38
        )

)
```

But [reading the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) I believe it needs to be something more like this

```
array(
'id' => $value
)
```

In addition, this is the PHP error in my error log

> [30-Jul-2020 03:42:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called
> **incorrectly**. Unsupported value type (object). Please
> see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information. (This message
> was added in version 4.8.2.) in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/wp-includes/functions.php on line
> 5167
>
> [30-Jul-2020 03:42:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string()
> expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1158
>
> [30-Jul-2020 03:42:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called
> **incorrectly**. Unsupported value type (object). Please
> see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information. (This message
> was added in version 4.8.2.) in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/wp-includes/functions.php on line
> 5167
>
> [30-Jul-2020 03:42:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string()
> expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in
> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myproject/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1158

Sorry it's long, but I wanted to be clear and show what I have tried and give a clear picture of what I'm doing.

Comment: If the UPDATE query you have shown already does what you want - then why are you performing a SELECT now, instead of just executing that UPDATE query via `$wpdb->query()` …?

Comment: For some reason with the upgrade to PHP 7, Wordpress isn't allowing me to use `$wpdb->query()`. I was previously and I came back to check after the upgrade and it completely broke.

Comment: Then just must have been using it wrong, because it still works fine in general, under PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `$wpdb->get_col()` instead of `$wpdb->get_results()`. Same thing but `get_col` returns a simple array of values (since we know you are only getting one column back), where as `get_results` returns and array of objects because you could be getting multiple columns.

Or you could do:

```php
$where = array('id' => $value->id);
// - or -
$where = (array) $value;
```

but in this case using:

```php
$get_ids = $wpdb->get_col("
    SELECT id
    FROM $database
    WHERE (`id` > 1 AND `expired` IS NULL)
");
```

is the proper thing to do.

See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

I believe your mysql prepare error is due to the fact you're passing the wrong value to the where clause and it can't be parse properly for the prepare function.

Comment: Thank you! `$wpdb->get_col()` was the key.